# Filtering an array of objects in React using lambda expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a delete button that filters out items from a list of items and updates the state variable.

```
public OnDeleteClick = (): void => {
  const selectionCount = this._selection.getSelectedCount();

  let newArray = this.state.items;

  for (let i = 0; i < selectionCount; i++) {
    const keyToBeRemoved = (this._selection.getSelection()[i] as any);
    const filteredItem = newArray.filter(item => item !== keyToBeRemoved);
    newArray = filteredItem;
  }
  this.setState({
    items: newArray
  })
}
```

This is working but I don't want to use the for loop.
So I wrote this.

```
public OnDeleteClick = (): void => {
  let selectedItems = (this._selection.getSelection() as {}[]);
  let itemsCopy = this.state.items;
  let newArray = itemsCopy.filter(x => x != selectedItems);
  this.setState({
    items: newArray
  })
}
```

But this wont filter out the items. What is not working?

Comment: Doesn't look like you're indexing items in `selectedItems` in your second snippet with the filter? (i.e. `x => selectedItems.indexOf(x) === -1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf()` function to check if the item is present in the selectedItems array and delete it if necessary.

```
public OnDeleteClick = (): void => {
  let selectedItems = (this._selection.getSelection() as {}[]);
  let itemsCopy = this.state.items;
  let newArray = itemsCopy.filter(x => selectedItems.indexOf(x) >= 0);
  this.setState({
    items: newArray
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negate the result of [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or even indexOf as in the other answer:

```
public OnDeleteClick = (): void => {
  let selectedItems = (this._selection.getSelection() as {}[]);
  this.setState({
    items: this.state.items.filter(
      item=>!selectedItems.includes(item)
        //using some
        // !selectedItems.some(
        //   selected=>
        //     selected===item
        // )
    ) 
  })
}
```

Comment: indexOf  is working fine but includes method apparently doesn't exist. Don't know why.

Comment: @AKronym You tried it with a browser that is [too old](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) and you didn't set the babel settings correctly for that browser? Or maybe your typescript definition files are out dated.

Comment: I am using the latest version of chrome and also for further verification i tried this code on [Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and it is throwing an error on the includes method.
`let arrObj1 = [
    {
        name: "ABC",
        age: 12
    },
    {
    name: "XYZ",
    age: 23
    }
];

let arrObj2 = [
    {
        name: "ABC",
        age: 12
    },
];


let arrObj3 = arrObj1.filter(x => arrObj2.includes(x) < 0);
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(arrObj3));`

Comment: @AKronym it's a [typescript setting](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/931)

Comment: Oh I see!. So it works in es7 only. Thank you so much!